# Adding block feature using swift and parse server

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform

So I'm dealing with app rejection "Guideline 1.2 - Safety - User Generated Content" and one of the features app want me to implement is "- A mechanism for users to block abusive users" Im not sure exactly how to put the code into action but know what i have to do which is

Step 1. Create class in Parse for blocked users, like: "Blocked"

Step 2. Create columns of type [String]: blockedBy & username (user is blocked)

Step 3. Query only users if current user is not in blocked list

Step 4. Add button to send PFObject to block a User

If someone can help i can provide info from my project. It would be much appreciated because I've been struggling with this for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.raywenderlich.com/98831/parse-tutorial-getting-started-web-backends tutorial. Great help, shows how to setup the local environment, the MongoDB, how to create a class within the local parse environment ran from the terminal, shows how to query, etc. Let me know if you have more specific questions I can help resolve.